# Solr smart next word Suggester (word that occurs most often)

Tags: solr, liferay, autosuggest, solr4, search-suggestion

I am integrating solr with liferay and I want implement smart next word suggester. for eg if title of my documents are following:

- Solr is best search engine in world
- Solr is implemented on lucene search engine
- Solr are lucene used by 80% of developers as search engine in world
- lucene doesn't require separate installation on app server for make search implementation

So if I type **Solr**, I should get following result :

1. solr
2. solr lucene
3. Solr search
4. solr engine
5. solr world

etc.

if I type **lucene**, I should get following result :

1. lucene
2. lucene search
3. lucene engine
4. lucene world

etc.

I tried lots of example and they works but I am facing following problems:

- Suggestions work if I start from prefix **Solr**, If I start typing any middle word, it doesn't work
- I am getting complete sentence not next best matching word.

Please help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Well, neither of your examples are actually the *next* word. Do you want the word that occurs most often in documents together with your term?

Comment: Yes, I want word that occurs most often.

Comment: Hi Yadav,

Can you explain me how did you  manage to make auto suggest with liferay and solr in?

Answer (score 0):

You can build "most popular other words" for the field by using facets. Ignore the facet with the same name as the word you're searching for and add a `fq` with the word (to limit it to the subset of documents that matches your word). Do this for each word you're searching for (i.e. ignore `solr` in the facet list generated and add `fq=title:solr` to the query).

Next step would be `fq=title:solr AND title:lucene` and skip `solr` and `lucene` in the list of facets.

This assumes that you're tokenizing your field approriately (with the StandardTokenizer or WhitespaceTokenizer for example) so you get one token for each word.

Answer (score 0):

AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory will give you suggestions if you type the middle word as well, hope that answers your first question